# How to use MiG with Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar

I right clicked my project, went to properties, libraries and added miglayout-4.0-swing.jar, but upon writing

```
JPanel mainwindow = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
```

in my project it cannot find the MigLayout class, and wants me to create it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A number of things come to mind: Restart netbeans, check project properties, libraries, make sure its still there. When you added it to the project, did you chose add Jar/Folder? You've added an import statement for the class right? Attempts to find it with ctrl+space (hit this twice) fail? Are you sure the jar file isn't corrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to `Tools -> Libraries` and create an entry for `MigLayout` like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6207429/261156). Then you add *that* library to your project.