# I m getting an error when run on tomcat (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, jar

When I have run my codes on tomcat , getting an error like this;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.istack.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/sun/istack/logging/Logger;
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.config.management.policy.ManagementAssertion.<clinit>(ManagementAssertion.java:87)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase.createManagedObjectManager(MonitorBase.java:177)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:196)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:174)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:602)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:344)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:326)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:308)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
at tr.com.ttnet.xmlns.services.ınquirecustomerovitreqabcs.ınquirecustomerovitreqabcs.InquireCustomerOvitReqABCSEp.getInquireCustomerOvitReqABCSPt(InquireCustomerOvitReqABCSEp.java:58)
at com.kafein.test.main(test.java:23)
```

Comment: wrong version of `Logger`...

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878077/nosuchmethoderror-com-sun-istack-logging-logger-getlogger